# Meteor Dynamic Template Events

Tags: templates, meteor

I'm new to Meteor, I could not find a sufficient answer to this but how does one go about referencing a Template's event handlers programmatically.

For example I would like to add or update or trigger an event defined in a template without actually as an example (pressing or clicking a button).

In the Template object I can see the events object below and can I access it but is this the right way?

**Template.myTemplate._tmpl_data.events[]**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the handler outside the event map and call it as a function:

```
someHandler = function(this, evt,tpl) {
  // do something with this, evt, and tpl
}

Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click .myButton': function(event,template) {
    var self = this;
    return someHandler(self, event,template);
  }
});

// Call someHandler whereever you want passing in whichever args you want
```

This is not a complete example, but should be able to get you going on some workable direction. If it works, please edit this answer to reflect a more complete example.

Comment: I don't really understand this solution if I call someHandler itself the context will be missing.  The easiest way to is to maybe use jquery eg trigger a click event.  I was hoping to look for something to dynamically access and/or create template events along the same lines I can dynamically create and access new templates...pls refer to the link below: [Dynamic Templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550775/how-to-compile-new-templates-at-runtime-in-meteor?rq=1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550775/how-to-compile-new-templates-at-runtime-in-meteor?rq=1

Comment: You can use event functions without their context so you can control that within the function and just trigger a context-free version. You can in fact use jQuery as your selectors within the template. But I think you are trying to do something else that is not that clear to me. Are you referring to triggering the event itself or the event handler? My example was for a handler. If you just want to trigger an event (eg a click) you can just use plain jquery and that will also get handled with your event handler definition.

Comment: Ok..I get it.  I'm trying to integrate PubNub into my Meteor app and based on certain pubnub message trigger a template event.....thanks this gave me some ideas!

Comment: Great! Do you need me to update the answer? You can also go ahead and update it with some relevant info and mark it answered so that other people reading this post will know how to solve a similar problem.